# Are the following coin flip events same?

Tags: probability

I was learning about Bernoulli trials and I am confused whether the presence of more than one person or more than one coin matters. I can't explain it properly, so I'm listing down three similar-looking events.

1. $A$ and $B$ each have a coin and each tosses his coin twice. Each toss is independent of the tosser's other coin and also of the other tosser's coins.
2. $A$ has two coins and he tosses each of them twice.
3. $A$ has a coin and he tosses it four times.
4. $A$ has four coins and he tosses them once each

In each case, $P(\text{Heads}) = p$ and $P(\text{Tails}) = 1-p$, where $p \in [0,1]$.

**Are the three events same?**

I think they are the same but I still have my doubts. For instance, $\{H,H,T,T\}$ is a single event for the third case. But for the first case, I am confused whether to account for which two tosses are made by which coin and similarly, for the first case, I am not sure if I am to account for which person makes which two tosses and which coin of his has which outcome.

**I think if you can write down the set of outcomes for each case, it will be the most helpful.**

Comment: tommy I think you should write out the outcomes for each case.

Comment: Usually these are all situations where the ultimate interpretation is of four independent Bernoulli random variables, but that's not necessarily a mathematical fact.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Can you tell me what you mean by "mathematical fact" in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every coin has the same probability of heads $P(H) = p$, and if the result of every toss is jointly independent of the result of all other tosses (whether or not the tosses are made with same coin), then multiple tosses with an individual coin are effecitvely equivalent to individual tosses with multiple coins. For this reason, in every case you described, that is, $1,2,3,$ and $4$, each one has a sample space of $16$ outcomes.

Comment: Thanks, let's pick the first case. $A$'s set of outcomes are $\{(H,H), (T,H), (H,T), (T,T)\}$ and similarly for $B$. The joint set of outcomes will be $\{((x,y),(z,w)) : x,y,z,w \in \{H,T\}\}$.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you (and also, the site doesn't allow me to upvote, sorry about that).

Comment: yeah, you got it! no problem. glad to help!